# Help guessing the solution to an optimal control problem

Tags: portfolio-optimization, minimum-variance

I am considering an investor facing a discrete-time multi-period minimization problem
$$
       \min_{\{v_t\}_{t=0}^\infty}\Bigg[\sum_{t=0}^\infty(1-\rho)^{t+1}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}v_{t}\Omega_{t+1}v_{t}'\bigg)+\frac{(1-\rho)^t}{2}\bigg(\frac{1}{2}\Delta v_t'\Lambda\Delta v_t\bigg) \Bigg] \quad \text{s.t.} \quad v_t'\textbf{1}=1 
$$
Let $v_t$ be a vector of weights attached to each asset, $\Omega_t$ be the time-varying covariance matrix and $\Lambda$ be a symmetric matrix of trading cost. Finally, $\rho\in(0,1)$ be the discount factor and $\textbf{1}$ being a vector of 1's. This problem has a corresponding value function
$$
    V(v_{t-1})=\min_{v_t}\Bigg[\frac{1}{2}\Delta v_t'\Lambda\Delta v_t+(1-\rho)\bigg(\frac{1}{2}v_{t}\Omega_{t+1}  v_{t}' +\mathbb{E}_t[V(v_{t})] \bigg)\Bigg] - \lambda(v_{t-1}'\textbf{1}-1)
$$

I am looking to find the Bellman equation via the 'guess and verify' method (similar to Gârleanu and Pedersen, 2013).

***Without*** the constraint ($v_{t-1}'\textbf{1}=1$), I can verify that
$$
V(v_t)=v_t'A_{vv}v_t+A_0
$$
is a solution with $A_{vv}$ a symmetric matrix of parameters. But with the constraint, I have been unable to find a guess that solves the problem. Can you find a suitable guess that includes the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

Your constraint of positions summing up to one would be strange unless you imply a long-only constraint as well.  There is no closed-form solution to mean-variance optimization with non-negativity (or box) constraints.  This is a standard quadratic programming problem, which can be efficiently handled numerically.  In a long/short context, position constraints are imposed in terms of $L_1$ or $L_2$ norm.  The former case wouldn't allow a closed-form solution either; the latter just adds to your $\Omega$ matrix.  Further generalizations, including non-local impact costs, slippage, continuous time, etc., are described in [my recent book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119821320).

Answer (score 0):

I thought that the standard mean-variance dynamic problem is actually time inconsistent. See for example: [Basak and Chabakauri (2010)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/40782974?seq=1)

Comment: An ungated version of the Basak Chabakauri paper can be downloaded with this link  https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/corpfinance/papers/2007.BasakChabakauri.pdf